# ElasticSearch - Combining query match with wildcard

Tags: json, elasticsearch, wildcard

I'm fairly new to ElasticSearch still, but I'm currently trying to wrap my head around why I am not able to mix a wildcard query with a match as well.

Take this JSON body for example

```
{
    "size":"10",
    "from":0,
    "index":"example",
    "type":"logs",
    "body":{
        "query":{
            "match":{
                "account":"1234"
            },
            "wildcard":{
                "_all":"*test*"
            }
        },
        "sort":{
            "timestamp":{
                "order":"desc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns with the error "*SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;*"
(Full dump: http://pastebin.com/uJJZm8fQ)

However, if I remove either the wildcard or match key from the request body - it returns results as expected.
I've been going through the documentation and I'm not really able to find any relevant content at all.
At first I thought it was to do with the _all parameter, but even if I explicitly specify a key, the same result occurs.

Before I assume that I should be using the 'bool' operator, or something alike to mix my query types, is there any explanation for this?

Comment: This error is because you have invalid json field index, (and there are other too). Are you doing direct CURL request, or using elasticsearch drivers for specific programming language?

Comment: I was originally using the official PHP library, but I've been doing debugging/testing with CURL.Can you elaborate on "invalid JSON field index"?

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that it does not understand the field "index". When querying Elasticsearch you include the index name and type in the URL. There is no wildcard search in a `match` query. There is a wildcard search in the `query_string` query.

Your query should be something like this with `match`:

```
POST /example/logs/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "account": "1234"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "timestamp" : {
      "order": "desc"
  }
}
```

Or something like this with `query_string`:

```
POST /example/logs/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query" : {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "account",
      "query": "*1234*"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "timestamp" : {
      "order": "desc"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Adding an example of a `wildcard` query:

```
POST /example/logs/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query" : {
    "wildcard": "*test*"
  },
  "sort": {
    "timestamp" : {
      "order": "desc"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "There is no wildcard search in a match query.", how is that possible when doing {"query":{"wildcard":{"_all":"*test*"}}} works as expected?

Comment: There are a lot of different query types in Elasticsearch. The snippet of json `{"query":{"wildcard":{"_all":"test"}}}` is a [`wildcard` query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html). That is not a [`match` query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). Each query type in Elasticsearch has a different format for the `query` object in the request. The way a `match` and `wildcard` query function is very different.